# Basic LWC SLDS but columns horizontally uneven

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, slds-grid

SLDS newbie here. Here's my html:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >
        <div class="slds-col slds-card slds-size_1-of-4">
            <p>First column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-card slds-size_1-of-4">
            <p>Second column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-card slds-size_1-of-4">
            <p>Third column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-card slds-size_1-of-4">
            <p>Fourth column</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This does nothing so the related js file is empty:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class SldsTest extends LightningElement {}
```

In Salesforce though, that first column sits higher than the others:
[image: "sldsTest" LWC showing 4 columns, the first being positioned higher that the others.]

This happens with only 2 or 3 columns too. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use lightning card instead of slds- card like below. It might help you to align columns horizontally in even manner.

```
    <template>
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-align_absolute-center">
         <p>First column</p>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>

    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-align_absolute-center">
         <p>Second column</p>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>

    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-align_absolute-center">
         <p>Third column</p>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>

    <lightning-card>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-align_absolute-center">
      <p>Fourth column</p>
    </div>
    </lightning-card>
</div>
</template>
```

Below is the screenshot :-
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this please, If this solves the issue please mark as best answer.
Edit -- I didn't mention the reason for this, so I've added a slds-List_horizontal class which can be used to get elements in a horizontal line. Here's the [ref](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/horizontal-list/) -

```
<template>
<div class="slds-list_horizontal">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >
        <div class="slds-col slds-card slds-size_1-of-4">
            <p>First column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-card slds-size_1-of-4">
            <p>Second column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-card slds-size_1-of-4">
            <p>Third column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-card slds-size_1-of-4">
            <p>Fourth column</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: A brief explanation of what changed would make this a better answer. It's not immediately obvious (at least to me) what changed.